# Url.Action() returns null in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

After migrating to the **ASP.NET Core 3.0**. The Url.Action() returns **null** for valid action, controller.  This worked in ASP.NET core 2.2

The action name **does not** contain async as explained in [Microsoft Doc for migration to core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#async-suffix-removal-from-controller-action-names)

**Configure** method

```
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

**ConfigureServices** method

```
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddControllersAsServices()
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
            .AddMvcLocalization();
```

**E.g.**

```
    // url is null
    string url = Url.Action("DeleteAccount", "Manage", null);
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: show us how you are using it?

Comment: I had some issues with routing that appeared to be because I missed swapping out the 'services.AddMvc' to 'services.AddRazorPage' I would double-check that you caught all the items that need to be removed from startup.

Comment: @mvermef  I am trying to validate the url in the unit test. For that, I am using the LinkGenerator from DI and I have created a custom mock EndPointUrlHelperMock that inherit from UrlHelperBase. Then Set this to the Controller.Url property. And looks like LinkGenerator.GetPathByAction(actionContext.Action, actionContext.Controller, actionContext.Values) returns null...

Comment: I'm seeing this issue too. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I am having the same issue with attribute routing using `IUrlHelper.Link(RouteName)`. route name is correctly set on the attribute and endpoints are configured with `MapControllers()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have met same question as yours.
I think you haven't AddNewtonsoftjson in your configureServices function.
Try to add it.

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
```

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```